# Unity2d: the player stop moving when I add an animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I have a problem in unity , the player mouvement is going good until I add an animation the player stop moving even if I press the keyboard keys,when I remove the animator compenent the player move normaly without problems !

I tried separate the animation script from the movement script and still theame problem , I don't think that the problem is comming from the code
playerAnimation code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerAnim : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator anim;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (rb.velocity.x == 0)
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        else
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
        else
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
    }
}
```

playerMovement script

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class playerControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Rigidbody2D rb;
        private float horizontal;
    
        public float runSpeed;
        public float jumpPower;
        public  bool inTheGround;
        private SpriteRenderer sp;
        Animator anim;
    
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            sp = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        }
        private void Update()
        {
            horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    
        }
        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * runSpeed, 
            rb.velocity.y);
         
        
    
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump")&& inTheGround)
            {
                
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x,jumpPower);
            }
            flipping();
            Debug.Log(rb.velocity.x);
    
        }
        private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("ground"))
                inTheGround = true;
        }
        private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
        {
            if 
           (other.gameObject.CompareTag("ground")&&rb.velocity.y>0.1)
                inTheGround = false;
        }
        void flipping()
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
                sp.flipX = false;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
                sp.flipX = true;
        }
       }
```

Comment: Your animator is interfering with your script. An animation is something that changes stuff over time. Your script handles movement, which is modifying the position over time. What could the animator possibly be changing to your object that causes your script to no longer have an effect? Try thinking about that.

Comment: I did check the apply motion root ,it is set to false and still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `Apply Root Motion` on Animator Component is set to `false`. This setting can overwrite your changes of the object's position over time. if not - can you please provide more information, perfectly a screenshot of your player components, and Animator Controller.

Comment: I did what you told me Mykyta and still not working can I get you discord so I can send you all the pictures?

Comment: It would help if you could update your question to include more information so that your question could be answered here. You mentioned you have an animation script. Can you provide this script if that is what you think causes the error.

Comment: ok , I updated the question, sorry i am new here in stackoverflow .

Comment: Your code looks correct and should not be the cause of your problem.  I would go step by step from the point where your player is walking, then add your animation script, then animator component without animations, then add run animation. This way you can check at what point your player stops moving. From your question I understand that it stops when you add animator controller to it, so I would look into that and into animation settings, if you want more help - please more information, maybe screenshots of mentioned components.

Comment: ok Mykyta , after I did many of your suggestion , I think that the problem is from one of the animations that changes the position of the player , in order to Make him go up and down when he is running,when i remove this animation everything goes good, so one question , is there any way to make this animation, I want the running animation to be my player go up and down (my player is a ball)

Comment: Hey, great to hear that you found an issue! there are multiple ways to go about your problem, first one would be to make your ball animation relative, [this link](https://www.highwaynorth.com/blogs/bryan/relative-position-animation-in-unity) explains the idea and general steps.

I am not sure if that will work outside of the box for you, you might need to move your scripts to the parent of the player and do some adjustments.

Another way is to edit the animation and remove x pos from the clip, you will still be able to move it on X, while the Y axis will be controlled by the animation.

Comment: Another solution will be to animate your ball in code using Tween library, for example [DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php), but it will require some more work. Both methods most likely will make you create a child object for the ball sprite, so that you can alter the sprite position while the player object (one with colliders and rigidbody) is controlled by your movement script. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much Mykyta! i checked the link you gave me and everything is working now .

Comment: Glad I could help, good luck with further development!